# zend Call to undefined method

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I'm trying to compare array values with MySQL table using PHP code. but I keep getting the error below:
Call to undefined method panel_import::query()

```
$availablePanel = array();
foreach ($panelists as $key => $value) {
    $availablePanel[] = $value->_user_data['email'];
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($availablePanel);
echo "</pre>";
$db = Zend_Registry::get('db');
$query = "SELECT email FROM user WHERE email IN('".implode("', '", $availablePanel)."')";
$array = array();
$result = $this->query($query);     
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $array[] = $data["email"];
}
```

the following array is the result of the first print_r

```
Array
(
    [0] => dani6.AlfaWolf6@test.com
    [1] => dani7.AlfaWolf7@test.com
    [2] => dani33.AlfaWolf33@test.com
    [3] => dani34.AlfaWolf34@test.com
)
```

I'm quite new to PHP so if this is too easy to spot please excuse me for that but I really tired all I can for the past 5 hours before I asked:!

Comment: `$result = $this->query($query);`  should be `$result = $db->query($query);  `

Comment: when I've it like that... I get the following error:    Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

Comment: Check Zend's API for the database object..  `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {`  should be more like `while($row = $result->fetchAll()) {` or `while($row = $result->fetchAssoc()) {`

Comment: Yea I tried both and the same error for both :( I checked to see if there's another zend's API for database object but wasn't successful